# How to view individual page tracking results in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

View page tracking results

I have added the Google tracking JS code to each page in my site:

```
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxxx-x', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview', '/virtuvalPath/myPageName');
```

I am getting results from Google Analytics, but the results are summarized for all pages. I want to see the page views for each specific page. How can I view the results for each individual page within Google Analytics?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either

1. Click into each individual page link in the All Pages report, or
2. Add an advanced filter to filter only for your specific page, or
3. Create a custom report with the specific page

There are probably other methods but these should be the most direct.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate your help!